# External users ends up twice in Azure AD B2C

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am setting up sign-in using Azure AD B2C in a web application, but for some reason my users end up twice in the AD. This is how it happens.

I invite a new user using the Graph API (or using the Azure Portal, same result)
The new user shows up in the user list in the Azure Portal as UserType=Guest and Source="Invited user". So far so good.

Now the user accepts the invitation. The Source of the newly created guest user is then changed to "External Azure Active Directory". I suppose that is ok.

Then the user logs in and gets through the signup process (I use the "Sign up and sign in" user flow). An additional user is being created in AD. UserType=Member and Source="Federated Azure Active Directory".

The login works as it should, but I end up with 2 users having the same name and username. One guest and one member. Is this how it is supposed to work? It's a little messy with all the users listed twice.

I have configured 2 identity providers in ADB2C. Email and OpenIdConnect. If the user clicks "Sign up" he gets to create a local account in B2C. But I want him to be able to use his credentials from his own organization if possible, using the OpenIdConnect provider.

This is how the OIDC provider is configured
[OIDC config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utWdS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invite a user through the AAD B2B guest invite feature, you are inviting an Azure AD user, not a B2C user.
You'd use the invite feature to invite other administrators for example.

You don't need to invite them if they don't need to do B2C administration.
They can sign up through the B2C signup flow directly.

*Except* as we discussed in the comments, you have ~30 different AADs you want to use and are using the underlying AAD of the B2C tenant as the IdP.
In this case your solution is basically correct.
Invite to the B2C tenant and then they can login using that external account.
There will be a duplicate user since the invited user is not a B2C user.
There might be some solution to combine the users with a custom policy, but I'm honestly not sure how you'd do that there.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But if I don't invite the user first, he gets this error when trying to login:
AADSTS50020: User account 'user@domain.dk' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/' does not exist in tenant 'My B2C Tenant' and cannot access the application 'yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy'(Login app) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

Comment: They selected the AAD as identity provider when going through signin/signup?

Comment: I have configured 2 identity providers in ADB2C. Email and OpenIdConnect.
If the user clicks "Sign up" he gets to create a local account in B2C. But I want him to be able to use his credentials from his own organization if possible, using the OpenIdConnect provider. So he clicks "Sign in with social account" and then he gets the error mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: There might be something wrong with that OIDC config. Could you add a screenshot of it to the question? You can erase the tenant id, client id etc. from the photo before upload.

Comment: Screenshot added to the question now.

Comment: Is the tenant id in the metadata URL the id of the external tenant?

Comment: No. It is the tenant id of the AD B2C tenant. I should add, that I have users in about 30 external organizations, that I want to be able to use my app. And that seems to work with my current setup, except that all users gets "doubled"

Comment: Now the error makes sense and my answer isn't exactly correct for you. The users get doubled because the B2C user is a separate entity from the guest user. And if you want to use the underlying AAD of your B2C tenant as the IdP, what you are doing is essentially the correct way. There might be some way to combine through use of custom policies, but I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: Ok. So I will use my current setup, and live with the fact that my users are doubled. Thank you for your swift answers. Your comments has helped me to a better understandig of what is going on.

Comment: One thing that you might want to check is do these invited users have access to the user list in Azure Portal. In our typical scenarios, we don't want users to be able to see who else is in the system. A B2C user would not be able to get a user list, but an external user in the AAD might be able to. This can be limited though through external user settings in AAD.